# How to understand the 5th Normal Form?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm using two online sources for gaining an understanding of the 5NF, without any rigor of Math and proofs.

1. [A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm) (by Kent. This one seems to have been reviewed and endorsed in one of his writings by none other than CJ Date himself)
2. [Fifth Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form) (Wikipedia article)

However, I'm unable to understand either of these references!

### Let's first examine Reference #1 (Kent's).

It says: *"But suppose that a certain rule was in effect: if an agent sells a certain product, and he represents a company making that product, then he sells that product for that company."*

and, then, goes on to break up the original table (all table names have been given by me)...

```
acp(agent, company, product)

-----------------------------
| AGENT | COMPANY | PRODUCT |
|-------+---------+---------|
| Smith | Ford    | car     | 
| Smith | Ford    | truck   | 
| Smith | GM      | car     | 
| Smith | GM      | truck   | 
| Jones | Ford    | car     | 
-----------------------------
```

... into 3 tables:

```
ac(agent, company)
cp(company, product)
ap(agent, product)

-------------------   ---------------------   ------------------- 
| AGENT | COMPANY |   | COMPANY | PRODUCT |   | AGENT | PRODUCT |
|-------+---------|   |---------+---------|   |-------+---------|
| Smith | Ford    |   | Ford    | car     |   | Smith | car     |
| Smith | GM      |   | Ford    | truck   |   | Smith | truck   |
| Jones | Ford    |   | GM      | car     |   | Jones | car     |
-------------------   | GM      | truck   |   -------------------
                      ---------------------
```

But I'm not even sure if I understand the English-language meaning of the above rule. My understanding of the above rule is that its *'then'* clause is totally redundant! For,

**IF** an agent is selling a product

**AND**

**IF** this agent is representing a company making that product,

**THEN, OBVIOUSLY,** this agent is selling that product for that company.

So, where is the 'rule' in this statement? It, in fact, seems to be a non-statement to me!

Working backwards from the three tables -- ac, cp, and ap -- it seems the rule really is: *"A company may make 1 or more products, an agent may represent 1 or more companies, and when representing a company he may or may not sell all its products."*

But the original table acp was already capturing this rule. So, I'm not sure what is going on here with the explanation of 5NF.

### Let's now examine Reference #2 (Wikipedia).

It says: *Suppose, however, that the following rule applies: "A Traveling Salesman has certain Brands and certain Product Types in his repertoire. If Brand B1 and Brand B2 are in his repertoire, and Product Type P is in his repertoire, then (assuming Brand B1 and Brand B2 both make Product Type P), the Traveling Salesman must offer products of Product Type P those made by Brand B1 and those made by Brand B2."*

Once again, going just by the English-language meaning of this rule and nothing else,

**IF** a salesman has brands B1 and B2, and product P with him,

**AND**

**IF** product P is made by both brands B1 and B2,

**THEN**, why on earth wouldn't he be able to offer product P of brands B1 and B2 just as he could in the original 3-column table 'sbp(salesman, brand, product)' which was serving well even before this new 'rule' came into effect?

Could somebody please clarify?

Comment: It should read "**only** he sells that product for that company". Couldn't the primary key just be (company, product)? That would implement the rule.

Comment: Nope, the moment you throw in '**only**', it becomes a totally different problem. I think, I've finally begun to grok what the rule is and therefore what the 5NF is. Inability to understand the rule was my problem, I believe. Thanks, regardless.

Comment: "OBVIOUSLY" is wrong. In general, "IF an agent is selling a product AND [] this agent is representing a company making that product" then it might or might not be the case that "this agent is selling that product for that company"; they might sell it only for other companies. But they must sell it for that company **when there's a rule that IF ... THEN ...**.  So a given business might or might not have that rule. PS `if x then y == (not x) or y` So **when there's a rule that EITHER NOT (...) OR ...**.

Comment: The Kent article is informal & doesn't give NF definitions, hence, is useless in isolation. It isn't a "simple guide", it is a "vague impression". If you read the referenced definitions, it's still quite poor at connecting its fuzzy prose to them, so it's not much more useful, ie not much more than useless, when read with them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See, it is much easier to understand the thing backwards.

First the **5NF**; a table (relational variable) is in the 5NF if decomposing it would not remove any redundancies. So, it is final NF as far as removing redundancy is concerned.

The original table obviously has some redundancy.  It claims that *"Smith represents Ford."* twice, and *"Smith represents GM."* twice.

So let's see is it possible to decompose this into two or more projections and reduce some redundancy.

Let's start backwards.

- *Company* exists.  `{COMPANY}`
- *Agent* exists.    `{AGENT}`
- *Product* exists.  `{PRODUCT}`
- *Company* makes *Product*. `{COMPANY, PRODUCT}`
- *Agent* represents *Company*. `{AGENT, COMPANY}`

A pause here; suppose a rule was *"If an agent represents a company, and the company makes a product, then the agent sells that product"*.

This would be simply  `{AGENT, COMPANY} JOIN {COMPANY, PRODUCT}` ; but this would generate an extra tuple, namely `(Jones, Ford, truck)`; which is not true because Jones does not sell trucks.

So, not every agent sells every product, hence it is necessary to state that explicitly.

- *Agent* sells *Product*. `{AGENT, PRODUCT}`

Now if we join

`{AGENT, COMPANY} JOIN {COMPANY, PRODUCT} JOIN {AGENT, PRODUCT}`

that extra tuple is eliminated by the join to the `{AGENT, PRODUCT}`.

To grasp things intuitively, the rule can be modified a bit.

**Original**

> If an agent sells a certain product, and he represents a company
>   making that product, then he sells that product for that company.

**Modified** (same meaning)

> If an **agent sells product**, and **agent represents company**,
>   and the **company makes that product**, then **agent sells that product for
>   that company**.

**Explained** (substitute from bullet points above)

> If  `{AGENT, PRODUCT}` and `{AGENT, COMPANY}` and `{COMPANY, PRODUCT}`
>   then `{AGENT, COMPANY, PRODUCT}`.

So,  the rule allows for the join to happen -- and hence the decomposition.

Now compare that to the predicate of the original table:

> *Agent* represents a *Company* and sells **some** *Product* that the company makes.

Not the same as the rule, so it is open to anomalies which would violate the rule -- see Bill Karwin's example.

---

**EDIT** (see comments below)

**Suppose** that we have the original table, but **not the rule**.

It is obvious that there is some redundancy in the table, so we may wonder if there is a way to remove that redundancy somehow -- usual way is decomposition into projections of the table.

So, after some tinkering, we figure out that it can be decomposed into `{AGENT, PRODUCT}, {AGENT, COMPANY}, {COMPANY, PRODUCT}`. Current data certainly allows for that -- as per your example.

And we do that, and whenever interested in *"Which agent sells which product from which company?"* the answer is simply

`{AGENT, COMPANY} JOIN {COMPANY, PRODUCT} JOIN {AGENT, PRODUCT}`

Then Honda shows up, and they make cars and trucks too.  Well, no problem there, just insert `(Honda, truck) , (Honda, car)` into `{COMPANY, PRODUCT}`.

Then Smith decides to sell Honda cars, but not trucks. Sorry, no way, oops! Because he already sells cars and trucks, if he wants to represent Honda, he has to sell both.

Because we would have tuples

```
(Smith, Honda) (Honda, truck) (Smith, truck)
               (Honda, car)   (Smith, car)
```

So we have **introduced** the rule! Really did not want to -- was just trying to get rid of some redundancy.

The question is now, was the original dataset just a fluke, or was it a result of a rule which was enforced somehow outside of the DB?

The author (Kent) claims that the rule exists and the design does not match it. Certainly, it would not be a problem for the original table to accept `(Smith, Honda, car)` only -- not requiring `(Smith, Honda, truck)`.

---

Theoretical point (ignore if boring)

The rule

`If {AGENT, PRODUCT} and {AGENT, COMPANY} and {COMPANY, PRODUCT} then {AGENT, COMPANY, PRODUCT}`; for every `(Agent, Company, Product)` triplet.

explicitly states that *join dependency*

`* { {AGENT, COMPANY}, {COMPANY, PRODUCT}, {AGENT, PRODUCT} }`

holds for the original table.

---

As often stated, cases like this are rare; actually so rare that even textbook examples have to introduce weird rules in order to explain the basic idea.

---

**EDIT II** (the fun part, but may help understanding)

**Suppose** that the rule does not exist, and there is explicit requirement that any agent can sell what ever he wants from any company -- hence the rule would be plain wrong.

In that case we have the original table

`{AGENT, COMPANY, PRODUCT}`

I would argue that:

1. Being all-key, it is in BCNF.
2. It can not be decomposed (current data may allow it, but future does not).
3. It is in BCNF, all key, it can not be decomposed, hence it is in 5NF.
4. It is in 5NF and is all-key, hence it is in 6NF.

So, it is the presence or non-existence of the rule that determines if the table is in BCNF or 6NF -- same table same data.

Answer (score 12):

All normal forms are meant to avoid anomalies, i.e. logical inconsistencies in data.

There's an anomaly possible when you violate 5th normal form, represented by this relation:

```
-----------------------------
| AGENT | COMPANY | PRODUCT |
|-------+---------+---------|
| Smith | Ford    | car     | 
| Smith | Ford    | truck   | 
| Smith | GM      | car     | 
| Jones | Ford    | car     | 
| Jones | GM      | truck   | 
-----------------------------
```

So we know Jones works for GM and Ford, and we know that Jones sells cars and trucks.  And we know (from Smith) that GM makes cars.  So why isn't there a row for `[Jones, GM, car]`?  That's an anomaly.  Jones *should* sell GM cars, but there's nothing in this table that makes that consistent.

**The problems comes from trying to use one relation to represent multiple independent facts.**
If we instead represent these independent facts as independent relations `ac`, `cp`, and `ap`, then we remove the possibility of anomalies.

---

Re your comment:

For purposes of this example, we assume that a salesman is motivated to sell anything he can.  If he *can* sell a type of vehicle, and he works for a company, and the company makes that type of vehicle, then the salesman will definitely sell it.

This premise is stated in William Kent's article:

> But suppose that a certain rule was in effect: if an agent sells a certain product, and he represents a company making that product, then he sells that product for that company.

So based on this premise, it's implicit that every possible valid combination should result in a row in the three-column table.  That's a business rule that we'd like the data to satisfy.

But in cases that our single table doesn't contain one of the rows necessary to be consistent with that premise, it fails to represent the business rule.  Basically, because it introduces the possibility that a "fact" is stored redundantly.

By separating the facts into three tables, each fact is stored exactly once.  The result of a JOIN between the three simpler tables naturally produces a relation that is like the original three-column table, except *guaranteed to have no anomalies.*

Comment: Bill, why do you say, *"Jones should sell GM cars..."*? Where in the rule does it say that ALL agents representing a company must sell ALL products for that company? Your example relation simply echoes what I've been thinking is the interpretation of the rule. Namely, an agent representing a company may sell only SOME and NOT ALL products that the company makes. I still feel there's something lacking either in the relation data, or in the statement of the rule itself to illustrate 5NF.

Answer (score 8):

"IF an agent is selling a product

AND

IF this agent is representing a company making that product,

THEN, OBVIOUSLY, this agent is selling that product for that company. "

This is just totally wrong.  Totally.  Think about it again.

Ford makes taxis.
Ford makes bycicles.
GM makes taxis.
GM makes bycicles.

I represent Ford.
I represent GM.
I sell taxis.
I sell bycicles.

Now, are all of these 8 statements true in the case where :

I sell taxis, but only the Ford kind.
I sell bycicles, but only the GM kind.

Answer : yes they are.

The fact that I represent Ford for some product and I sell bycicles for some manufacturer and Ford makes bycicles, does not logically imply that I sell Ford bycicles.

EDIT : further clarification and an attempt to address the actual question re. 5NF

The distinction between the case where the acp design is in 5NF, and must not (cannot) be decomposed and the case there the ACP design is not in 5NF, and must be decomposed, is precisely in whether or not there is a *BUSINESS* rule in effect that *DOES* "logically imply that I sell Ford bycicles" (to stick with the example).  *Logic alone* doesn't give us such a rule, but businesses can add all the rules they want.

*IF* such a rule is in effect, then the information in the acp design ("I sell Ford bycicles") does become logically derivable (not by virtue of logic alone but by virtue of the rule applying) from the other design, and the other design must be chosen (choosing to record information that is logically derivable constitutes redundancy wrt the "basic" information that it is derivable from, and therefore constitutes a violation of some NF).

*IF* no such rule is in effect, then the information in the acp design is not logically derivable from anything else, and it is then information that *must* be stated "individually".  No such rule means no derivability/redundancy and hence (speaking rather loosely and sloppily) no violation of a NF.